# About the definition of Fractional Ideals in Number Fields

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I'm currently working through

> Don Bernard Zagier - Zetafunktionen und quadratische Körper (1981)

(German for: Zeta functions and quadratic fields).

$K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is a quadratic number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ it's ring of integers. Zagier (page 88) defines an Ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ as a subgroup $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ with $\mathcal{O}_K \cdot \mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a}$. That means: 
$$
\lambda \in \mathcal{O}_K, \alpha \in \mathfrak{a} \implies \lambda\alpha \in \mathfrak{a}\hspace{45px}(1)
$$
Later on (page 89) he defines a Fractional Ideal as finitely a generated subgroup $\mathfrak{a} \subset K$ of $K$ (instead of $\mathcal{O}_K$) *for which (1) holds.*

Now I'm a little bit confused. Does he really mean (1) or does he mean:

$$
\lambda \in K \,\,(\text{instead of } \mathcal{O}_K), \alpha \in \mathfrak{a} \implies \lambda\alpha \in \mathfrak{a}
$$

Also why do we need the extra "*finitely generated*"?

**EDIT:**

I now do know, Zagier really meant (1) - otherwise the Fractional Ideals would just be Ideals of $K$ (since $K$ is a field there only exist two such Ideals $\{0\}$ and $K$ itself).

Comments suggest, that the "finitely generated" is equivalent the the statement, that for every Fractional Ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ there there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $n\mathfrak{a}$ is an Ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Now I need to understand why the equivalence holds. Any help is welcome!

Comment: The definition seems to be missing the condition that, for a fractional ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ there exists a $\gamma \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $\gamma \mathfrak{a} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ (sometimes called a common denominator).

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg That's exactly the next sentence (but not part of the definition). It'll probably be my next question. He writes: _For every Fractional Ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $n\mathfrak{a}$ is an Ideal (in the former sense)._ This seems more like a comment.

Comment: Note that finitely generated is part of the definition, this makes his definition equivalent with the one given above by @ÍgjøgnumMeg

Comment: It's really $(1)$. If we required $\lambda \alpha \in \mathfrak{a}$ for all $\lambda \in K$, then we'd have an ideal of $K$, and there are only two of those - $\{0\}$ and $K$. We want an $\mathcal{O}_K$-submodule of the $\mathcal{O}_K$-module $K$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Can you elaborate further in an answer? I'd be happy to accept it!

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right! Since $K$ is a field itself! Thank you for the clarification. My next question is stated in the comment above, if you know a way to show the equivalence I'd be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Asume that a fractional ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is generated by the elements $z_1,z_2,\ldots, z_n\in K$ (as a $\mathcal{O}_K$-module). For all $i$ we can find $x_i\in\mathcal{O}_K$ and $r_i\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $z_i=x_i/r_i$. Set $r=l.c.m.\{r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n\}$. Then $r\mathfrak{a}\subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$. The other direction is easier because any ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is finitely generated.